AttributeError appears while importing sciann
I am using following packages:
Tensorflow Version: 2.16.1,
Keras Version: 3.3.3.dev2024060803,
Python Version: Python 3.11.7 ,
Conda Version: conda 24.5.0
While running the code "import sciann as sn", I am getting this error:
"AttributeError: module 'keras.api.backend' has no attribute 'get_graph'".
I have tried by all means. I am expecting somebody help me to fix this error. I wish to play with the codes of sciann.

Did you read the documentation?  sciann is an orphaned project.  Its support stopped with tensorflow 2.10.  You should try loading that older tensorflow.  https://github.com/sciann/sciann
